# Functioning Problem In Accelerometer

Tags: arduino, accelerometer

Hello I have used ADXL335 Accelerometer in a gesture controlled project but I have powerd by 5v output from Arduino Lilypad, so it started creating mess by giving wrong outputs. Afterward I came to know that it operates at 3.6V from data sheet but now how to provide 3.6 V to Accelerometer as Arduino gives 5v output.Hope gets solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to provide 3.6 V to Accelerometer

1. You can use a standard 3.3 V Linear regulator to convert 5 V to 3.3 V 
   [image]
2. If you have 3 V or a 3.3 V Zener diode you can use it too as a shunt regulator.
   [image]
3. The typical current is about **350 uA**. You can create a simple resistive voltage divider with 100 ohms ad 200 ohms as shown. The side effect is that, there will be continuous loss of about 16 mA of current. The droop will be less as the sensor load current is >20 times less than the current flowing through the resistors.

[image]

You can change the values to 200 Ohms and 400 Ohms too depending on how much the 3.3 V will drop when you connect the sensor to it.
[image]

Comment: Thank You Soo Much